# I want to place images over a div that has a specific background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a div (100% wide and height auto). It will have this background image

[image]

And i want to place cars over this div.

[image]

The positions of the cars will be determined by the API.

The end result will be something like this.

[image]

Is is possible to achieve? Please guide me if it is possible. Thankyou.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: Is this hard-coded or dynamically positioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple and basic example of how you can do it using pure html and css:

```css
.car-park {
    width: 1200px;
    height:439px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2BwR.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .car {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZYO1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 19px;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .car-1 {
    top: 50px;
    left: 195px;
  }
  
  .car-2 {
    top: 295px;
    left: 295px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="car-park">
  <div class="car car-1"></div>
  <div class="car car-2"></div>
</div>
```

You can also control the size of the car like this:

```css
.car {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZYO1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 19px;
  height:40px;
}

.car-lg {
  width: 22.8px;
  height:48px;
}

.car-xl {
  width: 28.8px;
  height:60px;
}

.margin-bottom-10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="car margin-bottom-10"></div>
<div class="car car-lg margin-bottom-10"></div>
<div class="car car-xl margin-bottom-10"></div>
```

This is how you set the background to 100% width:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.car-park {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% * 1020 / 439);
  max-height: 439px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2BwR.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-park"></div>
```

Comment: can we do it in percentage instead of pixels?

Comment: And map in percentage too because of the responsiveness?

Comment: @AliZia I'm sorry but this is too complicated for a question without any attempts (No HTML/CSS) - You must try it yourself first and if you have and difficulties then you can ask a question, but this time it should also include the code that you tried and a clear description of the issues you're having with it.

Comment: But I did provided you with a good place to start, with example of background sizes (The second code snippet) and also positioning (First code snippet) - You can try "playing" with it and understand how to fit in exactly to your needs

Comment: @AliZia Please also take a look at the third snippet - I hope it will help you with the 100% width

Comment: Just a last thing. Is it possible to make the car-park width div equal to 100% but if map is large, we apply horizontal scroll on just the map div?

Comment: @AliZia Are you talking about 100% width or height?  We wrote a comment at the same time so i'm not sure if you saw my last edit when you posted it

Comment: I want it to fix 100% width

Comment: @AliZia In that case, I think the last code snippet is exactly what you're looking for :)

Comment: Let me give it a try and then I will let you know bro

Comment: The map disappeared. Maybe because of relative?

Comment: No, you need to give the `body {min-height: 100vh;}` which will ensure that the height of the body is relatively at least to 100% of the height of the viewport. It will allow the image to show because it's a background (Hense not having a height like an `img` tag)

Comment: Can you have a look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyajleg0rmjz602/parking.rar?dl=0 . This is my latest code till now.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the exact style of the 3rd code snippet? Note that it's different from the first one  (`background-size: contain;` + `height: calc(100% * 1020 / 439);` + `max-height: 439px;`) - I can't look at it at the moment because I have to go

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure I copied the 3rd snippet

Comment: I tried it but i want the map to be on 100% of screen size wide

Answer (score 1):

You can position the cars with `position: absolute;`:

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="img/car.png" class="car car-1">
 <img src="img/car.png" class="car car-2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: url(img/parking.png) no-repeat top left / 100% auto;
  width: ...; height: ...;
}
.car {
  position: absolute;
}
.car-1 {
  top: ...; left: ...;
}
.car-2 {
  top: ...; left: ...;
}
```

Comment: Can we do this in percentage because this map is somewhere in the center of an app. and what if we scroll? The cars mis-align?